# Worldpay extension for Magento

Tags: magento, e-commerce, worldpay

I have a Magento store setup and installed this extension:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/worldpay-extension.html

when you goto:

Admin>Configuration>Payment Methods

you are greeted with this php error message:

Fatal error: Class 'Phoenix_Worldpay_Helper_Data' not found in < my website >/app/Mage.php on line 516.

From what I have read about helper classes it is looking for the directory the helper class is in.

The helper class exists and is in the right location:

/app/code/community/Phoenix/Worldpay/Helper/Data.php

Im using Magento community v 1.6.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Go to: `/app/etc/modules/Phoenix_Worldpay.xml`, `/app/code/community/Phoenix/Worldpay/etc/config.xml` and `/app/code/community/Phoenix/Worldpay/etc/system.xml` make sure your XML isn't messed up.  Get rid of any blank lines.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Just re looked over all the xml files and they are all in good order, no spelling mistakes and or extra lines.

Comment: Try uninstalling and reinstalling the extension.  After you're done, refresh all of your cache.  I was able to install this extension on my sandbox CE 1.6 with no problem.

Comment: cache is disabled (Flushed it anyway) and ive tried uninstalling, reinstalling, logging out and in again all to no avail.

Comment: There cannot be anything wrong with the XML or it would be looking for `Mage_Worldpay_Helper_Data` instead, or the module might not load at all. When clearing the cache also consider clearing `var/connect/` and `var/package/` folders otherwise reinstallation might be reinstalling a broken copy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The possible causes for this I am aware of are:

- File does not exist. (You've checked this)
- File exists but has wrong permissions, typically it should be 644 (read-write, read, read)
- File exists but class name is wrong. It must be the same as the path with `/` replaced by `_`
- File exists but code is malformed so class is never registered.
- Compilation is enabled and hasn't been rebuilt.

Comment: I feel a little stupid now :(

Compiling did the trick, thanks alot.